# SQL select output to XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005

Trying to do a select in SQL Server 2005 and send the output to xml. Table 2 is a general use table with various types of info. Some product info is in there if it's type 2, it's a sales lead if it's type 1. We can have multiple sales leads and products for each case_num from table 1.

**Table 1**

```
case_num, 
date
```

**table 2** (general use)

```
case_num,
rec_type (1=sales lead; 2=product),
various info based on type in generic columns =
col_a,
col_b,
```

I'm trying something like:

```
select 
    case.case_num
    ,case.date
    ,product.col_a as product_name
    ,product.col_b as product_price
    ,lead.col_a as sales_lead_name
    ,lead.col_b as sales_lead_address
from 
    table_1 case
    ,table_2 product
    ,table_2 lead
where 
     (case.case_num = product.case_num AND product.rec_type = 2)
     OR
     (case.case_num = lead.case_num AND lead.rec_type = 1)
for xml auto, elements
```

This is bringing back results like

```
<case>
   <case_num>1</case_num>
   <date>1/1/2013</date>
   <product>
      <product_name>name</product_name>
      <product_price>1.00</product_price>
      <lead>
         <sales_lead_name>bob smith</sales_lead_name>
         <sales_lead_address>address 1</sales_lead_address>
      </lead>
   </product>
   <product>
      <product_name>name2</product_name>
      <product_price>2.00</product_price>
      <lead>
         <sales_lead_name>bob smith</sales_lead_name>
         <sales_lead_address>address 1</sales_lead_address>
      </lead>
   </product>
</case>
```

I don't want the name repeating for every product. With multiple products and multiple leads, how do I format the SQL so it doesn't make sort of a Cartesian product in my results?

I made another example to illustrate my problem.  [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f937f/1)
This is making a cartesian result, matching all parts to all persons.  I want to have one case then each part then each person, then close case.

I was trying DISTINCT and getting errors.  I thought about UNION to tie two together, but I don't think I can do that within a bigger select for my case.

What I’m getting:

```
CASE_NUM    DATE    PART_NAME   PART_PRICE  PERSON_NAME COMPANY
1   2013-01-01  stapler 1.00    bob smith   acme supplies
1   2013-01-01  matches 2.00    bob smith   acme supplies
1   2013-01-01  stapler 1.00    john doe    john supply inc
1   2013-01-01  matches 2.00    john doe    john supply inc
```

What I want:

```
CASE_NUM    DATE    PART_NAME   PART_PRICE  PERSON_NAME COMPANY
1   2013-01-01          bob smith   acme supplies
1   2013-01-01          john doe    john supply inc
1   2013-01-01  matches 2.00        
1   2013-01-01  stapler 1.00
```

Comment: In what XML format do you want your output ??

Comment: This is pretty standard XML output..

Comment: and what is your expected output ??

Comment: I want to have case, lead1, lead2, lead3, prod1, prod2, prod3, close case

Comment: but since I'm going to the same table for two sets of data and I can have multiples of each, I didn't know if it was doable with sql

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend suggested only joining once, then filtering the select based on case statements and I think this is going to work.  Thanks folks

```
select case_num = case 
                when child.rec_type = '1' then mast.case_num
                when child.rec_type = '2' then mast.case_num 
              else '' end

     ,mast_date = case 
                when child.rec_type = '1' then mast.date
                when child.rec_type = '2' then mast.date
              else '' end

  ,child.rec_type
  ,part_name = case when child.rec_type = '1' then child.col_a else '' end
  ,part_price = case when child.rec_type = '1' then child.col_b else '' end
  ,subject_name = case when child.rec_type = '2' then child.col_a else '' end
  ,subject_type = case when child.rec_type = '2' then child.col_b else '' end

from table_master mast
join table_child child on mast.case_num = child.case_num
--for xml auto, elements;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has answered the question I have done something similar in the past I cant exactly remember how I did it but I will give you something to play with its really hard to guess things when you dont have data available , as far as I remember I did something like this to get the format you are after and it was on SQL Server 2005 so it should work for you

```
select case.case_num, case.date,
                    (SELECT col_a   [@productname]
                            ,col_b  [@productprice]

                    FROM table_2 t2
                    WHERE t2.case_num = case.case_num 
                    FOR XML PATH('Details'), TYPE)
from table_1 case 
FOR XML PATH('Case'), ROOT('Cases')
```

Answer (score 0):

As @marc_s points out, you create your Cartesian product yourself by 'joining' the tables the way you do. Always try to use `JOIN` instead.
I believe the following query would fit you needs:

```
select 
    [case].case_num
    ,[case].date
    ,lead.col_a as sales_lead_name
    ,lead.col_b as sales_lead_address
    ,product.col_a as product_name
    ,product.col_b as product_price
from 
    table_1 [case]
JOIN table_2 lead ON [case].case_num = lead.case_num 
  AND lead.rec_type = 1
JOIN table_2 product ON [case].case_num = product.case_num 
  AND product.rec_type = 2
FOR XML auto, elements;
```

You can view it on [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fcac/4)

The output will look like this:

```
<case>
   <case_num>1</case_num>
   <date>2013-01-01</date>
   <lead>
      <sales_lead_name>bob smith</sales_lead_name>
      <sales_lead_address>address 1</sales_lead_address>
      <product>
         <product_name>name</product_name>
         <product_price>1.00</product_price>
      </product>
      <product>
         <product_name>name2</product_name>
         <product_price>2.00</product_price>
      </product>
   </lead>
</case>
```

Comment: That assumes that I have one lead and multiple products.  In reality, I can have multiple leads and multiple products.  In this example, if I select the multiple (products) first, it gives me:

Comment: <case><case_num>1</case_num><date>2013-01-01</date><product><product_name>name</product_name><product_price>1.00</product_price><lead><sales_lead_name>bob smith</sales_lead_name><sales_lead_address>address 1</sales_lead_address></lead></product><product><product_name>name2</product_name><product_price>2.00</product_price><lead><sales_lead_name>bob smith</sales_lead_name><sales_lead_address>address 1</sales_lead_address></lead></product></case>

Comment: and makes the lead a repeated subset of product